# How does the Natural Semantic Metalanguage deal with proper names?

Tags: semantics, proper-nouns, natural-semantic-metalanguage

The natural semantic metalanguage gives definitions of common words in terms of semantic primes, as can be found [here](https://intranet.secure.griffith.edu.au/schools-departments/natural-semantic-metalanguage/semantic-explications).

I am curious, however, as to how the NSM deals with proper names (or does it?) For example, does the NSM have an explication for the expression `Donald Trump'?

Comment: You are thinking of something with first name male person (or famous duck), first name basis because prominent person, child or familiar one?

Comment: @JoopEggen uhh what?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 um, how do you define "proper name"? Is _Donald Trump_ one proper name or two? Is there a semantic structure involved -- a meaning? If it's just an arbitrary referent, then it is just a fixed reference to "somebody" in an NSM structure; if you want structure, you'll have to add predicates for "family name" and "personal name", or whatever else you find necessary.

Comment: @jlawler Sure. But the idea of the NSM aid that it should be able to provide an explication, in terms of primes, of any expression that is not a prime. It doesn’t matter if DT is one word or two; the idea of a fixed referent should not be allowed in the NSM.

Comment: I don't believe NSM makes the claim that every word that is not a prime can be explicated. Proper nouns can be seen as belonging to the iconic-indexical part of language and therefore are not amenable to semantic analysis, so they are sometimes said to be semantically transparent. Another such part of language is onomatopoeia.